# How to do html_safe on yield in sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, slim-lang

Currently, I am practicing a Sinatra app. I am using slim for views.

In my app/views/layout.slim i have

```
h1 Sinatra App
= yield
```

In my app/views/index.slim file i have

```
h3 Index page
```

When i go to index route, it shows `<h3>Index Page</h3>` as a string. Is there a way that i can i do html_safe on yield ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
h1 Sinatra App
== yield
```